# Bower and jquery.slimscroll 1.3.2

Tags: bower

The latest jquery.slimscroll, version 1.3.2 has a fix for issue [95](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/issues/95) in it -- see the attachWheel function at line [378](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/blob/master/jquery.slimscroll.js).  But Bower thinks the latest jquery.slimscroll is version 1.3.1 and attempting to register 1.3.2 generates a "Duplicate Package" error.  When I download the latest version with Bower and inspect attachWheel I see the line causing error 95 (and also see the error in FireFox).

Here's the command I used:

```
C:\<dir> bower register jquery.slimscroll https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll
```

Is there a Bower bug?

Answer (score 0):

There is no [git tagged 1.3.2 version](https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/releases). Ask the author to tag it.

Answer (score 0):

There is now v1.3.3 as well as a v1.3.2 https://github.com/rochal/jQuery-slimScroll/releases